# Guidance on Python Lists?

Tags: python

I have three sorted lists (i.e., in terms of values, keys) as:

```
N1: [(100, 'T'), (40, 'D'), (20, 'J'), (10, 'C'), (1, 'P')]
N2: [(60, 'T'), (50, 'D'), (30, 'J'), (8, 'C'), (2, 'P')]
N3: [(50, 'T'), (30, 'D'), (20, 'J'), (10, 'C'), (1, 'P')]`
```

I want to see that, out of N1, N2, and N3, which one has the highest and lowest values for T, D, J, C, and P respecitively. I want to create five temporary lists with range of values of T, D, J, C, and P but with their respective list identifications too, i.e., something which says, T={100 for N1, 60 for N2, 50 for N3}. Your suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Also, i want to see that if i input my order of preference as J, D, and T (or any three preference pair), the best list out of N1, N2, and N3 gets selected in terms of their values.

Comment: You did mention in the comment that ["Letter Codes are infact Keys and (Value, Key) pairs in N1, N2, and N3 were all fetched out from their respective Dictionaries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519628/guidance-on-python-lists#comment76031326_44519775). Could you please update your question to show your original dictionaries and how you approached the problem? I think there might be a much easier way to solve the problem using the "original dictionaries" than what you showed here. Please don't forget to include the desired output. :)

Comment: Please don't post it in the comments, just [edit] the question :)

Comment: Done and thank you for your help. I am actually myself learning Python and trying to implement different algorithms.

Comment: @engqureshi Hope below my answer would help you...? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Haranadh ... not exactly. However, your solution was really helpful [By the way, it was not about Network IDs ... you did mentioned Network IDs in your comments section :-)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your questiond what I understand is your sample inputs could be 
 `input = [T, D, J]` or  `input = [D,J,P]`

You want to do the caliculations on `N1`, `N2`, `N3`. and find out the output.
Then
If respective sample outputs would be 
`[('N1', ('T', 100)), ('N2', ('D', 50)), ('N2', ('J', 30))]` ,
`[('N2', ('D', 50)), ('N2', ('J', 30)), ('N2', ('P', 2))]`

Then the solution is as follows.

```
#These are some pre decleration supporting constants...
T , D, J, C, P = 'T' , 'D', 'J', 'C', 'P'
NW = [ 'N1', 'N2', 'N3']

#These are actual input data.
N1 = [(100, 'T'), (40, 'D'), (20, 'J'), (10, 'C'), (1, 'P')]
N2 = [(60, 'T'), (50, 'D'), (30, 'J'), (8, 'C'), (2, 'P')]
N3 = [(50, 'T'), (30, 'D'), (20, 'J'), (10, 'C'), (1, 'P')]
swp_tup = lambda N_list: [(t[1], t[0]) for t in N_list] #swaping

#Just creating the swapped tuples collection. This can be avoided by changing the code while creationg of N1, N2, N3.
data = [swp_tup(N1), swp_tup(N2), swp_tup(N3)]

#Creating transpose of given data... to do actual caliculation.
transpose =  zip(*data)

# Finding the max value of each row, This row was a column in input data.
def calculate(input_list):
    """Returning the NetworkID with Max for each input type

    >>> calculate(['T','D','J'])
    [('N1', ('T', 100)), ('N2', ('D', 50)), ('N2', ('J', 30))]
    >>> calculate(['D','J','P'])
    [('N2', ('D', 50)), ('N2', ('J', 30)), ('N2', ('P', 2))]
    """
    output = list()
    for i, curr_data in enumerate(transpose):
        # finding max of current row.
        m = max(curr_data)
        # checking if the value is there in given input.
        if m[0] in input_list:
            results = [i for i, j in enumerate(curr_data) if j == m]
            output.append((NW[results[0]] , m))

    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print calculate( [D,J,P] )
```

You can optimize as per your need. Defenetly there can be better optimized code. :)

Similarly min also can be done.

If your question is changed, then this solution is no valid. :)

Comment: Thank you. I am grateful. I am working on it and would share a version here too. Could you please let me know that what are these lines exactly doing in the code 1. 'swp_tup = lambda N_list: [(t[1], t[0]) for t in N_list', 2. 'results = [i for i, j in enumerate(curr_data) if j == m]', and 3) '(output.append((NW[results[0]] , m))'

Sorry for the basic questions. The loop appeared confusing to me.

Comment: `1st point:` 
A lambda function to  iterate through the input list and swap the given tuples. 
Actually example is: N1 will be converted to  `[('T', 100), ('D', 40), ('J', 20), ('C', 10), ('P', 1)]`
similarly for any list of tuple will be swapped. it only works proper for tuple of two elements.

`2nd point:` m represents max value. the results will holds all the occurrences positions of max value. 

`3rd point:` trying to construct a list of tuples with combination of first max occurrence Network's Name and actual max value.

Comment: @engqureshi hope this helps.

Comment: One important thing is for large data-sets this solution may needs to be optimised further. just FYI.

Comment: @ Haranadh ... thank you for your all help and support. It really helped me alot.

Comment: @engqureshi : if it is helpful you can upvote. It would have been good if you  put your question correctly. You would have got better help.

Answer (score -4):

I advise against creating separate variables, as this seems to rather be a task for dictionary, with your letter codes as keys.

Comment: Well, the Letter Codes are infact Keys and (Value, Key) pairs in N1, N2, and N3 were all fetched out from their respective Dictionaries